# What is the best place to store authentication tokens client side

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, oauth-2.0, access-token

When my users are authenticated they receive an authentication token, I need to use this authentication token to authorize some asp.net WebAPI calls. To do this I need to add the token to the head of that call, so I need the token accessible from the users browser. I think that storing the token in a cookie isn't the safest way, so what is the safest way to store that token and still accessible in my javascript to make API call's?

Comment: It all depends on how important the security of the token itself needs to be. For example, what damage could be inflicted if a token was compromised? Bearing in mind your token is only as secure as your clients physical device.

Comment: Then they can access the data of the compromised user.

Comment: Well that's a given, I was thinking more along the lines of what sort of damage could they do when they have access to said data i.e. would they have access to sensitive information like passwords, bank information etc? It's important to understand what you are protecting, it helps better understand what level of security is needed.

Comment: FYI this question would probably be better placed on the [security.stackexchange.com](http://security.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Thanks I'll post it there.